# Convert square bracket notation array from javascript to C# using JSON?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have this:

```
var testArray = [];
testArray["First"] = "First Test Data";
testArray["Second"] = "Second Test Data";
$.toJSON(testArray);
```

I then pass it back to server side. When I look at the object server side in handling the AJAX request all I have is "[]".

Is there a way to do this or something similar to achieve the ability to look up data passed back from the client?

Comment: It sounds like your `toJSON` implementation is not converting to Json correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an array, but then you are using it as an object. Create an object instead, and it will be handled correctly:

```
var testObject = {};
testObject["First"] = "First Test Data";
testObject["Second"] = "Second Test Data";
$.toJSON(testObject);
```

or simply:

```
var testObject = {
  First: "First Test Data",
  Second: "Second Test Data"
};
$.toJSON(testObject);
```

If you really want an array, then you access the items using numbers, not strings:

```
var testArray = [];
testArray[0] = "First Test Data";
testArray[1] = "Second Test Data";
$.toJSON(testArray);
```

or simply:

```
var testArray = ["First Test Data", "Second Test Data"];
$.toJSON(testArray);
```

Comment: I had no idea! JavaScript let me use it happily for quite some time. How weird. Thanks for the examples!

Comment: @Sean Anderson: Yes, an array is also an object, so that usage is not an error (but may be confusing), but when the `toJSON` method serialises the array it will detect that it's an array and only include the array items, not it's object properties.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make `testArray` an [**object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects):

```
var testArray = {};
```

The way you use arrays is not correct. Arrays only should have values with numerical indices. Otherwise you just add a property to the array object and these are ignored when converted to JSON.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AACQM/)